# azure devops, bash : 'az pipelines variable-group variable update'

Tags: bash, azure-devops

```
        az pipelines variable-group variable update \
      --group-id X \
      --name ${{parameter.Key}} \
      --value ${{parameter.Value}} \
      --org $(System.CollectionUri) \
      --project $(System.TeamProject)
```

Is there an option to reach `variable-group` by name and not by `group-id`?

Answer (score 1):

> have option to reach variable group by name and not by group-id?

The answer is no.

According to the document [az pipelines variable-group variable update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/variable-group/variable?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-variable-group-variable-update)：

```
az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id
                                            --name
                                            [--detect {false, true}]
                                            [--new-name]
                                            [--org]
                                            [--project]
                                            [--prompt-value {false, true}]
                                            [--secret {false, true}]
                                            [--value]
```

**Required Parameters**

> ```
>   --group-id --id
> Id of the variable group.
>
>   --name
> Name of the variable.
> ```

The group-id is the Required Parameter.